# Factoring a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

How can I write the function $f(z)=1-0.7z-0.3z^{-1}$, $z$ complex, as $f^+(z) f^-(z)$, where

1. $f^+(z)$ is free of zeros and singularities **outside and on** the unit circle
2. $f^-(z)$ is free of zeros and singularities **inside and on** the unit circle.

As can be verified, $f$ has a single pole at $z=0$ and two zeros at $z=1$ and $z=3/7$, so I cannot simply take $f^+(z)=f(z)$ and $f^-(z)=1$.

Comment: Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/307483.

Comment: Notice that [the Wiener-Hopf decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Hopf_method) can also be about decompositions as sums, not only as products. And the domains of definition of $f^+$ and $f^-$ may be the upper and, respectively, lower half-plane, not only the unit disk and its exterior. SO maybe you'll have to rethink the decomposition itself and the domains of definition.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for the comment. The main problem is that I cannot find too much theory on the Discrete-time Wiener-Hopf problem. The original decomposition have to do with half planes, but in discrete-time, they have to do with inside and outside the unit circle. That's my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f^+ (1) f^- (1) = f(1) = 0$, either $f^+(1) = 0$, or $f^-(1) = 0$. Either case contradicts your requirements, so such a factoring is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(z)=1-0.7z-0.3z^{-1}=\dfrac{-7z^2+10z-3}{10z}=\dfrac{-7(z-1)(z-\frac37)}{10z}$$
$$f(z)=\dfrac{-7}{10}\cdot(z-\frac37)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)$$

then
$$f^+=\dfrac{-7}{10}~~~,~~~f^-=(z-\frac37)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)$$

Comment: $f^-$ has a zero at $z=1$. Doesn't work :(

Comment: $f^-$ still has a zero at $z=1$. My requirements are: no zeros at unit circle.

Comment: @user108128, $f^-$ must not have its zeroes on the circle, by requirement. I believe that it would be better to delete this answer.